# Office 365 like ccapabilities on ubuntu

Tags: cloud, office365

I have recently fully switched over to Ubuntu as my daily driver and quickly realized how convenient Office 365 was. I constantly use word, excel and powerpoint along with OneNote and OneDrive. I am not attached to the office suite i am attached to its capabilities. So i really just want to know if there is an alternative full suite out there for Ubuntu that I just havent been able to find. Something with Word, Excel, and Powerpoint (the easy stuff) with auto cloud sync capabilities, a note taking software and a Cloud Service.

I know I may be asking a lot but this is just one capability I wish I still had from Windows. Aside from that I am loving being part of the Linux community.

Comment: LibreOffice has most of what you are looking for, and can read and write office documents.

Comment: Of course, you could also create an account at [https://www.office.com/](https://www.office.com/)

Comment: +1 for LibreOffice, with eventually a Box/Dropbox client.

Comment: I have an office 365 enterprise account. The webapps do not have the full capabilities of the full apps. its like using office on your phone. I want something that is fully functional on linux. LibreOffice just doesnt have a good option for cloud integration.

Comment: There's no *equivalent* service with full integration in ubuntu, closest I've gotten is buying a Crossover for Linux license, and then used that to install Office 365 with its latest "Office" installation templates, seems to work with Word, Excel, Powerpoint, fairly well, though I haven't tested its cloudsync capabilities.  (It's basically just WINE driven but with specific sets of things installed, etc. per a template in Crossover's database of apps)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like LibreOffice, you should try some WPS Office on http://wps-community.org/ or FreeOffice on https://www.freeoffice.com. For the Sync Capability, Nextcloud should do the job, they even offer 2GB free in cloud based.

Be careful that WPS and FreeOffice are not open source.